# MS word fails to print a kind of documents, the other documents are printed successfully

Tags: pdf, printing, ms-word

we use windows 10 20H2 release. MS Office 2019.
Description:
The template downloaded from a gouvernment portal causes Error. We have about 500 documents made from this template. The documents cause following Error, cut from Windows logs:
***Microsoft Word
There is insufficient memory or disk space. Word cannot display the requested font.
P1: 200549
P2: 16.0.13801.20294
P3: 9f9u3P4:***

All other documents will be printed successfully. The text pasted in new document as text will be printed w/o problems.
It seams to be a special Word symbol what caused the problem. All ways to solve the problem is tried out. No success.
The template could I sen for analyze.

The problem exists on all systems, by printing on HP Printers, but also during the printing into a PDF file.

Thanks for help.

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUGqs.png)

Comment: could you please add screenshots for clarity?

Comment: This is not a programming question. As such it is off-topic for Stack Overflow and should be posted on an appropriate end-user forum (e.g. MS Answers).

Comment: Screenshot added